# asking user for an integer to be searched in an array

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm learning to deal with data structures and I've just written a program which Insertion_Sorts an array of integers.
The Sorting works perfectly well, so there;s no need to tackle it.
But I wish to give my user a way to search for a specific number in a Sorted array.
and it doesn't work: more specifically: 
i've compiled the following code in MS VS 2010 under Win7 x64 Ultimate, and after writing "Specify number to be searched" it crashes, and the debugger says "Access violation".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int swap(int x, int y)
{
if(x != y)
  {
       _asm
      {
        mov eax,x;
        mov ebx, y;
        mov y,eax;
        mov x, ebx;
      }

  }
return 0;
}

int insertion_sort()
{
int or_size = 2;
int i,j,k,h, size, temp;
char answ;
int xx;
char query [20];


printf("Specify array size\n");
scanf_s("%d", &size);
printf(" Now, input all elements of the array \n");

vector<int> Array(size, 0);
if (size > or_size)
    Array.resize(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    scanf_s("%d\n", &temp);
    Array[i] = temp;
}

printf ("Your array appears to be as follows: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d  ", Array[i]);


for (i =0; i < size; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (Array[j] > Array[i])
        {
        temp = Array[j];
        Array[j] = Array[i];
        for (k = i ; k > j ; k-- )
                    Array[k] = Array[k - 1] ;

        Array[k + 1] = temp ;
        }
printf ("\n Your Array has been insertion_sorted and should know look like this: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", Array[i]);

printf("\n Would you like to search for a specific value? (Yy/Nn) \n");
answ = _getch();
if (answ == 'Y' || answ == 'y')
{
    printf("Specify number to be searched \n");
    scanf_s("%s", query);
    xx = atoi(query);
    printf("Searching for %d ", query);
    for(h = 0; h < sizeof(Array); h++)
        if (Array.at(h) == xx)
            printf("%d\n", h); 
        else
            printf("No such number was found in a sorted array\n");
}    

Array.clear();

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    insertion_sort();
    return 0;
}
```

PS ignore the _asm part: it works, but hasn't been used yet :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("Searching for %d ", query);` Since `query` is declared an array of `char`, you shouldn't use the `%d` specifier which is used to print signed integers, change `%d` to `%s` or `query` to `xx`. Since this is C++, I would use `std::cout` though.

`sizeof(Array)` doesn't do what you want it to do. Use `Array.size()` instead.

In C++, you don't have to declare all your variables at the beginning of the function. That was an old part of C89 I believe. This means you can declare your for loop like this `for(int h = 0; h < Array.size(); h++)` for example.

Here is a good example of trying to find something in a vector:

```
if(std::find(Array.begin(), Array.end(), xx) != Array.end())
    std::cout << "found" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
```

You are mixing C and C++ code. I would recommend choosing one language and using only that language.

Comment: I won't, later on, but for now I know a bit of both and am learning more C++.